# Create and Use Dynamic Library with Resources in Qt

Tags: qt, dynamic, dll, shared-libraries

I have created a Dynamic Library using Qt Creator which I have included in another Qt Project but when I call functions with works with resource files for example reading the contents of a .txt in resources, it does not work.

Once I have the Build of the Dynamic Library which created the `*.so`, `*.a` and the `qrc_resources.cpp` files in another folder outside the library project folder, example:

- Project Folder: `/home/username/Qt Project/library/`
- Build Folder: `/home/username/Qt Project/build-library/`

I then copy the build files into the library project folder and from the test project (a Qt Application Project), I right click on the project -> Add Library -> External Library -> Select the .so file (from the library project folder which I just copied).

Then, after including the header files and calling a function which reads the contents of a file from the `qrc` resources, it does not work.

**UPDATE**

I used a QFile to check if the Resource File exists in which it does but I get this error: `QIODevice::read (QFile, ":/file.txt"): device not open`

Comment: Please add more information about used technique and code. Best provide a simple compileable example to review your approach.

Comment: I have included a bit more information, is it sufficient?

Comment: This not a compilable expample, at least not for the compilers I heard of. Nevertheless, you are trying to access the libraries ressource file within the test application? read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library

Comment: Isn't the default option Compiled-In?

Comment: I used a QFile to check if the Resource File exists in which it does but I get this error: QIODevice::read (QFile, ":/file.txt"): device not open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adding Libraries to Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html)

later

I think need to [create an external resource file.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html#external-binary-resources)

Comment: But doesn't the Compiled-In Resources include the resources in the library?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the problem by using a `QFile` object instead of `ifstream` object to open and read the file.